# SVN Tortoise: E720087: Can't get exclusive lock on file Repo\db\txn-current-lock': The parameter is incorrect

Tags: svn, repository, commit

I have a repository on a linux system and my working copy is on a windows system managed by SVN Tortoise. I have been using it for years but now suddenly, when I try to commit the data, I get the error:

> Can't get exclusive lock on file Repo\db\txn-current-lock': The parameter is incorrect

Most of the similar posts have an error of "permission denied" on this file, however, for me it is "parameter is incorrect". I don't know how to fix it. I have full control over the repository folder "drwx------"

Can anyone help to fix this problem to be able to commit my files again?

Comment: Perform an SVN Clean up with options of `Break Locks`, `Clean up working copy status` and `Fix Time stamps` selected and after doing clean up perform lock stealing to get the lock on the file

Comment: I have done the clean up with the mentioned options, but  I don't get how to perform "lock stealing"

Comment: This is how you can [Steal Lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQWV9.jpg). This basically lets you take exclusive control. If that doesnt work. Perform force breaking the lock from server using `svn unlock --force http://svn.example.com/repos/project/trunk/somefile.txt
'somefile.txt' unlocked.` This command will definitely fix whatever issues is there with the locking and then you can proceed with normal locking procedure. Hope i am clear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
When I try "steal lock", first I got an error that some files don't exist, since they are on my working copy but not yet backed up to the repo. After I de-select them, I get the error
"Can't get exclusive lock on file 'Repo_location\db\write-lock': The parameter is incorrect"

for the other command that you mentioned, I am not sure what should be the file that I target (in your example "somefile.txt")

Comment: Okay i was pretty sure that would have worked.. Now we need to try using svnadmin to clear this from the server itself... So you need to go to location where the repository is created... Perform `svnadmin lstxns` See if there are any transactions that are limiting this.. If it returns nothing then we need to see.... If it returns a list of transactions then you should perform the following command `svnadmin rmtxns yourreposname 'svnadmin lstxns yourreposname'`. This command will basically perform cleanup from server side

Comment: yes, I believe that the problem might be from the repo side.
Performing svnadmin lstxns gives ==>

0-0 and 24-s

and when I write the other command I get the following error
svnadmin: E160053: malformed txn id '`svnadmin'
svnadmin: E160053: malformed txn id 'lstxns'
svnadmin: E160053: malformed txn id 'myreposname`'

Comment: Oh sorry my bad...syntax error you need to use ` instead of ' . You need to use something like [this](https://paste.lucko.me/n9Qq5QHsvx)

Comment: I tried both ` and  ', however, I keep getting the same error

Comment: okay we will separate the commands out.. first try only rmtxns `svnadmin rmtxns myreposname` if it asks for the argument pass the above elements in the list to it something like `svnadmin rmtxns myreposname 24-s`

Comment: svnadmin rmtxns myrepo 24-s ==>
svnadmin: E160014: Reference to non-existent node '0.0.t24-s' in filesystem 'myrepo/db'

I get this error. I tried both the 0-0 and 24-s. I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: This means the node is no longer in play. Are you sure this is what is currently seen in `svnadmin lstxns myreposname`. If it returns empty then you can try locking and unlocking again. Can you also share `svnadmin info myreposname`? I want to check whether it is fsfs file system or berkely db...

Comment: Yes, I did it again to be sure. >svnadmin lstxns myrepo ==>
0-0
24-s. Running the other command gives the following: >svnadmin info myrepo ==>
Path: myrepo
UUID: ab32f14e-97bb-454b-a55a-77d988337ffc
Revisions: 50
Repository Format: 5
Compatible With Version: 1.9.0
Repository Capability: mergeinfo
Filesystem Type: fsfs
Filesystem Format: 7
FSFS Sharded: yes
FSFS Shard Size: 1000
FSFS Shards Packed: 0/0
FSFS Logical Addressing: yes
Configuration File: myrepo\db\fsfs.conf

Comment: This is something i have not seen.... I faced similar issue and was resolved by this rmtxns step..  Now i am not sure how to help you... This usually works.... Let me look into docs now and see if i can come up with something that has not been done right now..

Comment: One question though I am running the same on the ubuntu machine and  i have the following flags `drwxrwxrwx 2 apache-user apache-user 0 Mar 26 22:43 myreposname`. Did you always had only directory read and write flags active and not the file read and write flags?? Did you try by giving your apache-user the file read write and execution right??

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for checking.

I am not sure what you mean about the permissions. I always had read, write execute permissions on the folder, as per the output here==>
 drwx------  10 user user_group    340 May 10  myrepo